# Simplified Chinese to English MT result - fundamental mistranslation

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am using the generic NMT and found a serious mistranslation:

Source- 若中英文条款有不一致之处，以**中文**条款为准

Target- In the event of any inconsistency between the Chinese and English terms, the **English** terms shall prevail

The correct translation should be "the **Chinese** terms shall prevail".

Not sure if there is a official way to report/ improve MT result, if so, could you please also provide me the link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should raise this point in uservoice, as suggested on their portal [here](https://translator.microsoft.com/help/contact/):
[image]

But it looks like the link is broken on this page, so I suggest using this uservoice forum: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/558796-translator-api